# Select-AzSubscription OR Set-AzContext throws Please provide a valid tenant or a valid subscription

Tags: azure-functions, powershell-core

I am running a PowerShell Core Azure Function where I am trying to switch the AZ context to the Subscription that I need, by using the following cmdlets

```
Set-AzContext -Subscription "my subscription id" -Tenant "my tenant id"
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId "my subscription id" -Tenant "my tenant id"
```

Since this morning (Australia), I am getting the error

```
Please provide a valid tenant or a valid subscription
```

It seems like an Azure issue since this was perfectly functional until Friday (2 days ago). Any ideas or work arounds that I could use?

Answer (score 1):

**I tried to reproduce the code you provided for setting up the context in the Subscription level from the Azure Functions (PowerShell Core 7.0) and it is successful:**

- I tried by giving the `Subscription Name`, `Subscription Id` and also reversing the Set & Select Statements as you can see below output screenshots:

[image]

[image]

As you got this error:

```
Please provide a valid tenant or a valid subscription
```

**Make sure you passed the correct Tenant Id and Subscription Id belongs to specified Tenant Id.**

***To Check through PowerShell, You can run the `Get-AzTenant` and `Get-AzSubscription` in the PowerShell Command Line Interface:***

[image]

**Check your subscription ID available in the specified tenant Id list.**

**(OR)**

- We Can check the `Tenant ID` and `Subscription Id` through the `profile.ps1` of **Azure PowerShell Function Project itself** and can set the values from context to subscription level.
- If any value is invalid, then we can see the error message as well as you can compare the given `Subscription/Tenant IDs` with the list displayed in the terminal itself as you can see below the function (`Http Trigger`) also executed successfully:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is working now withut me changing anything. Could be a one off thing specific to Azure Region, mine was North Europe.